# How should I compile ES modules and run them without package.json and tsconfig.json?

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules

I created a minimalistic example of using ES modules in Typescript, using only the `tsc` and `node` commands. It works fine but I'm not sure I did it correctly.

I created two files like the following.

```
// test.mts
export function test(s: string) {
    console.log('test, s:' + s);
}
```

```
// main.mts
import {test} from './test.mjs'

test('a')
console.log('done')
```

And I compiled and ran like the following.

```
$ tsc --module es6 test.mts main.mts && node main.mjs
```

It seems I have to use the 'mts' extension instead of the 'ts' for source files, and have to import the 'test.mts' module with the 'mjs' extension. Am I correct? Is there any better method?

I am not a seasoned JS developer and the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) does not help in my case.

Comment: Look at the nodejs documentation, not the typescript documentation.

Comment: @Bergi, You mean one like [Determining module system](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#determining-module-system)? I already read that and came to the above result. I am wondering if there exists a feature of the ```tsc``` which automatically resolves a 'mts' file and translates the extension to 'mjs'.